# coupled vector equations

Tags: vector-analysis

So I am trying to solve some problems from Hughston and Tod's Introduction to General Relativity.
I need help with the following system of equations:

$$aX_i+bY_i=P_i$$
$$\epsilon_{ijk} X_jY_k=Q_i$$

From the first equation we get:
$$Y_i=P_i/b-aX_i/b$$

plugging into the second equation yields:
$$\epsilon_{ijk} X_j P_k=b Q_i$$
Now I am stuck and not sure how to solve it. Help would be appreciated. Please if possible use index-notation.

Comment: Are you interested in a solution in vector notation rather than suffix notation?

Comment: @David Quinn: Yea since nobody is writing, might as well be interested in a solution involving vector notation.

Comment: there appears to be no *unique* solution for $X$ and $Y$ but there is a method for finding *a* solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vector form we can write the equations as $$a\underline{x}+b\underline{y}=\underline{p}$$ and $$\underline{x}\times\underline{y}=\underline{q}.$$
Therefore the vectors $\underline{x}$, $\underline{y}$ and $\underline{p}$ are co-planar, and $\underline{q}$ is perpendicular to this plane. It follows that $\underline{p}\times\underline{q}$ is parallel to this plane and perpendicular to $\underline{p}$.

Therefore the vectors $\underline{x}$ and $\underline{y}$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $\underline{p}$ and $\underline{p}\times\underline{q}$.

If we therefore write $$\underline{x}=A\underline{p}+B\underline{p}\times\underline{q}$$
and $$\underline{y}=C\underline{p}+D\underline{p}\times\underline{q}$$ We can substitute these expressions into the given equations.

From the first we obtain $$aA+bC=1$$ and $$aB+bD=0$$

Calculating $\underline{x}\times\underline{y}$ using the vector triple product formula, gives $$(AD-BC)\left[\underline{p}(p \cdot q)-\underline{q}p^2\right]=\underline{q}$$

This leads to a third equation $$AD-BC=-\frac{1}{P^2}$$

Solving these equations, at least in part, determines that $$B=\frac{b}{p^2}$$ and $$D=-\frac{a}{p^2}$$ whereas $A$ and $C$ are arbitrary and are chosen to satisfy $$aA+bC=1$$

Comment: very nice solution. I like the "Ansatz" method to it.